# The string field is required. even thou there is no Required attribute in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building a simple Asp.Net Core app in linux(pop os). I am using VueJs + Aps.Net Core 3.1.101
I am trying to do a POST call to my app and my model is like below:

```
public class AddConfigurationContextValueApiRequest
{
    public int ContextId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Value is required to continue")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Value can not be longer than 500 characters")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Display name can not be longer than 500 characters")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } 
}
```

As you can see there is not `Required` attribute for the `DisplayName` field, but whenever I pass a `null` value from VueJS app for this field I get `The DisplayName field is required.`.

I am trying to figure out why would AspNet Core complain for this, since there is no `Required` attribute for such field!

Does anybody know if this intentional ? I tried to remove the `StringLength` attribute and still it triggers required attribute.

My action is fairly simple:

```
[HttpPost(UrlPath + "addConfigurationContextValue")]
public async Task AddConfigurationContextValue([FromBody]AddConfigurationContextValueApiRequest request)
{
    using var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkProvider.GetOrCreate();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Here it throws because ModelState is invalid
        throw new BadRequestException(ModelState.GetErrors());
    }

    //do stuff

    await unitOfWork.CommitAndCheckAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's peculiar. On quick glance, everything _looks_ correct. I can also confirm that the `[StringLength()]` attribute _shouldn't_ imply `[Required]`. I have binding models with e.g. `[StringLength(250)]` which are not marked as `[Required]` and pass a `ModelState.IsValid` check if they're `null`.

Comment: Do you happen to have the C# 8 Nullable Reference Types feature enabled?

Comment: @devNull: That did it for me, thanks. Set the "<Nullable>disable</Nullable>" in your project file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @devNull's suggestion I found out that somehow while I was playing around with Rider IDE it seems it switched that feature on!

There is an option in rider that allows to change that configuration on project level:

If somebody has the same problem: right click on the project level, go to properties, Application and there you can see this configuration.

Thank you @devNull for the help :)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have seen the same issue where the .csproj Nullable setting caused a property that was not marked as `[Required]` to act as though it were. I took a different approach than changing the Nullable settings in the .csproj file.

In my case it came down to a property that is required by the database; but the model allows null during POST as this particular property is a secret from the user. So I had avoided changing `string` to `string?` initially.

Once again, the Fluent API has provided an alternative solution.

Original Property

```
[JsonIgnore]
[StringLength(15)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Updated Property

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Fluent API Directives (in your DbContext file)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
  builder.Entity<MyClass>(c => {
    c.Property(p => p.MyProperty)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(15)
      .IsFixedLength();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently .NET 6 Web APIs have the "Nullable" property added by default. I simply had to remove it.

.csproj file:

[image]

Edit: As Luke pointed out (without elaborating any further), the above behavior is working as intended and actually makes sense. If your JSON has a null value, your code might crash, if not handled. Throwing a compile time error is impossible, since the JSON is unknown. Forcing yourself to using nullable reference types makes the code more resilient.

I haven't checked yet, how swagger behaves, the default config surely doesn't care about a .NET 6 setting and will no longer flag mandatory fields, if you leave out the [Required] attribute and use only nullable reference types to point out what is mandatory and what isn't.

Comment: Same for me. This is nuts.

Comment: This is bad advice. Rightly or wrongly, nullable reference types are now a feature in .Net 6 and this disables the whole feature. Instead, the better advice is to understand the value of nullable reference types and mark any non-required properties as nullable with the question mark like The Thirsty Ape describes.

Comment: It's a good solution if you are migrating an older project to .NET 6+.